# Python: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, csv, nonetype

I am trying to read a CSV and add it to list of objects.

This is the class code

```
class ReportItem:
    '''
    classdocs
    '''
    def __init__(self, hostname, jdbcDbname):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.jdbcDbname = jdbcDbname
        self.dbname = None
        self.schema = None
        self.shortName = None
        self.totalRows = None
        self.archivedRows = None
        self.deletedRows = None
        self.deletedSizeMB = None
        self.totalSizeMB = None
        self.archivedSizeMB = None
        self.deletedSizeMB = None

    def setDbname(self, dbname):
        self.dbname = dbname

    def setSchema(self, schema):
        self.schema = schema

    def setShortName(self, shortName):
        self.shortName = shortName

    def setTotalRows(self, totalRows):
        self.totalRows = totalRows

    def setArchivedRows(self, archivedRows):
        self.archivedRows = archivedRows

    def setDeletedRows(self, deletedRows):
        self.deletedRows = deletedRows

    def setTotalSizeMB(self, totalSizeMB):
        self.totalSizeMB = totalSizeMB

    def setArchivedSizeMB(self, archivedSizeMB):
        self.archivedSizeMB = archivedSizeMB

    def setDeletedSizeMB(self, deletedSizeMB):
        self.deletedSizeMB = deletedSizeMB
```

This is the implementation code:

```
import csv
from ReportItem import ReportItem

reportList = []

with open('Tables.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(csvfile.read(1024))
    csvfile.seek(0)
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='\'')
    if has_header:
        next(csvfile, None)
    for col in csvReader:
        reportItem = ReportItem(col[0], col[1])
        reportItem.setDbname(col[2])
        reportItem.setSchema(col[3])
        reportItem.setShortName(col[4])
        reportItem.setTotalRows(col[5])
        reportItem.setArchivedRows(col[6])
        reportItem.setDeletedRows(col[7])
        reportItem.totalSizeMB(col[8])
        reportItem.archivedSizeMB(col[9])
        reportItem.setDeletedSizeMB(col[10])
        reportList.append(reportItem)


for ri in reportList:
    print(ri.dbname)
```

The CSV contents will look like:
xxx xx  xxxx    xxxx    xxxxx   -1  0.06    -1  -1  -1  -1

This had resulted in the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CSVImporter.py", line 25, in <module>
    reportItem.totalSizeMB(col[8])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Another concern is that this col[8] may also be represented using scientific notation like 1.000E5. What is the best way to approach this issue?

Comment: Which begs the question, why are you writing functions to set things in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the reason. In the implementation you call the totalSizeMB variable that you define in the **init** function of the class. Variables do not take arguments. (maybe you meant the function, setTotalSizeMB)

If this is the case, then there is the same problem right under it (archivedSizeMB)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a typo. Your code should be

```
reportItem.setTotalSizeMB(col[8])
```

rather than

```
reportItem.totalSizeMB(col[8])
```

There is no function totalSizeMB in your class.